# iText7 text value is hidden

Tags: c#, pdf, text, styling, itext7

I have a secured [PDF Template](https://github.com/Dusernajder/PdfTemplate) with editable fields. When I set a field's value it doesn't show up until I click on it and modify it.

Code for inserting a value into a field:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(desktopPath + "PdfTemplate.pdf"))
        {
            reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
            using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(desktopPath + "ModifiedPdfTemplate.pdf")))
            {
                PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
                IDictionary<string, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
                fields["Date"].SetValue("DATE");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what an unedited field looks like:

[image]

After I run the code, the field still looks like before, but there is a value if I click on it:

[image]

After I modified the field (added a space at the end), now it shows the text:

[image]

I think it's because there is some styling on the field. How can I achieve that is shown on the last picture?

**Software Versions:**

*Itext* -> 7.1.16

*Adobe Acrobat* -> 2020.009.20063

Comment: Hey, could you share a sample PDF that reproduces the problem? With form fields, the original PDF is a decisive factor for debugging an issue

Comment: Hey, sure thing

Comment: The "Date"s field name in the template is not the same, I've changed it in the question for clarity

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the PDF you provided, the edited value appears immediately in Adobe Acrobat Reader. (Well, obviously I first had to change the field name from "Date" to "Tekstveld 52" as there is no field named "Date" in the example but field  "Tekstveld 52" looks like the field in your screen shots.) There might be an issue in some older version of the software packages involved, though, so please indicate exactly your iText version and your Adobe Acrobat Reader version. Also please check whether you have shared the correct PDF.

Comment: I've tried out with the provided template and it reproduces the same issue on my end, sure I'll provide software versions versions as well

Comment: Ok, I was still using 7.1.15, but after updating to 7.1.16 still no problem. But I use Adobe Acrobat Reader 2021.001.20155. Please try updating your Acrobat Reader and check again. If you still get a problem, please also share the result PDF you get for analysis.

Comment: I myself just updated Adobe Acrobat Reader to 2021.007.20091, still no problem.

Comment: Okay, the problem was the version of Adobe Acrobat, now that I have upgraded it, it works as intended. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Shall I create an answer from the comments or do you want to do so yourself?

Comment: Well, you were the one who helped me, so I'll let you get the points for it. :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the attempt to reproduce the issue here failed, the next step was comparing versions of software involved.

Synchronizing the iText version to the current 7.1.16 still resulted in different observations.

But then updating the PDF viewer, Adobe Acrobat (Reader), finally resolved the issue.

Apparently Acrobat 2020.009.20063 fails to display the field properly while Acrobat 2021.001.20155 and 2021.007.20091 succeed.

(One might think that basic functionality like field value showing should have been stable in Acrobat for a number of years. But apparently changes do still occur here. This may be related to hardening of signed forms against forgery in the recent months and years.)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, It was due to the font of the Form field, set the font value to null while creating the field or update the font of the existing field.
if the font is null Itext will use the document's default font